# How to compute matsubara frequency summation over computer?

Tags: solid-state-physics, computational-physics, many-body

Matsubara frequency sum usually takes the following form:
$S_\eta = \frac{1}{\beta}\sum_{i\omega_n} g(i\omega_n).$

But in my problem, $g(i\omega_n)$ is a lengthy expression, which can not be simplified by hand. So the only way I can do is to compute it in PC. But my question is: do we sum all of the $\omega_n$? Does the n tend to $\infty$?

The $g(i\omega_n)$ is to long, so I do not think it is ok to post here.
Do anyone has the experience of computing Matsubara frequency sum over computer?

Comment: Would [scicomp.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Did you try to continuate $S_\eta$ in the complex plan?